# Use GPU and CPU wisely

Tags: opencl

I'm newbie for OpenCL, just started learning. I wanted to know whether it is possible to execute few threads on GPU and remaining threads on CPU? In other words, if I launch 100 threads and assume that I've 8 core CPU then is it possible that 8 threads out of 100 threads will execute on CPU and remaining 92 threads will run on GPU?Can OpenCL help me to do this job smoothly?

Comment: No, that isn't at all how OpenCL works.

Comment: Ohh...@talonmies so how can I achieve such job?With Pthreads on host side?

Answer (score 5):

> I wanted to know whether it is possible to execute few threads on GPU and remaining threads on CPU?

Yes

> In other words, if I launch 100 threads and assume that I've 8 core CPU then is it possible that 8 threads out of 100 threads will execute on CPU and remaining 92 threads will run on GPU?

No. That description suggests that you'd be viewing the GPU & CPU as a single compute resource. You can't do that.

That doesn't mean you can't have both working on the same task.

- The GPU and CPU will be considered to be separate OpenCL devices.
- You can write code that can talk to multiple devices.
- You can compile the same kernel for multiple devices.
- You can ask for multiple devices to do work at the same time.

...but...

- None of this is automatic.
- OpenCL won't split a single NDRange (or equivalent) call between multiple devices.
- This means you'd have to schedule tasks between the two devices yourself.
- There's going to be quite a large disparity in speed, so keeping it optimal will require more than "92 here, 8 there".

What I've found works better is having the CPU work on a different task whilst the GPU is working. Maybe preparing the next piece of work for the GPU, or post-processing the results from the GPU. Sometimes this is normal code. Sometimes it's OpenCL.

Comment: Sometimes you cannot parallelize an algorithm, in that case CPU works faster than GPU so I wanted to give such task to CPU and let GPU do the work which it can do in better manner.
I read few research papers about performance difference between CUDA and OpenCL and found that OpenCL does NOT perform better than CUDA so apart from portability is it worthwhile to invest some time in OpenCL to get performance benefit?

Comment: Indeed, sometimes an algorithm has no parallelism to exploit, so keeping that on the CPU makes sense, especially if you can give the GPU something else to do. In terms of this discussion CUDA vs OpenCL is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple openCL devices to work on your algorithm, but the workload needs to be partitioned subtly enough so the work across devices is balanced properly, or else the overhead may make your runtime worse.

It is stated clearly in the [AMD OpenCL Programming Guide section 4.7](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/amdappsdk/assets/AMD_Accelerated_Parallel_Processing_OpenCL_Programming_Guide.pdf) about using multiple OpenCL devices, so my answer is, yes, you can divide the **work** to be executed with multiple devices, smoothly, **if and only if** your scheduling algorithm is smart enough to balance the whole thing.

Comment: I'm working with nVIDIA GPUs and I guess, this trick can also work with their GPUs right?

Comment: Yes, you can. But as like I said, only if you have a good scheduling algorithm, and btw there are many variables you have to consider to make a good one, like memory transfer overhead, usage of shared memory, how large will your kernel use registers, all of those will affect the load-balance scheduler.

Comment: Note that it's very easy to overload your CPU. You MUST avoid it otherwise your GPU will stay without work most of the time because CPU is busy on computing and cannot process events. Look at the excellent article about [Device Fisson from Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-device-fission-for-cpu-performance/)

Answer (score 0):

openCL code is compiled at run time for the selected device (CPU, model of GPU)

You can switch which target you use for different tasks  but you can't (with any implementation I know of) split the same task between CPU and GPU

Comment: somewhat related question can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245592/is-possible-to-span-an-opencl-kernel-to-run-concurrently-on-cpu-and-gpu?rq=1....but i'm not able to nderstand it clearly..